# Pascal Triangle in without loops?

Tags: python, functional-programming, erlang

I am trying to implement a Pascal triangle whose 1st row is 0 without using import functions such as lists. While I think it is fairly easy to do in more common languages like Python, I can not seem to put into my mind how I can do it in Erlang. With that, any help on how I can solve this is appreciated.

```
-module(s).

-compile(export_all).

main()->
    pascal(3).


calc(X, Y) ->
    if
    Y == 0 -> 1;
    X == Y -> 1;
    true -> calc(X-1, Y-1) + calc(X-1, Y)
    end.

pascal(N) -> 
    Row = 0,
    Col = 0,
    pascal1(N, Row, Col).

pascal1(N, Row, Col) ->
    if
    Row =< N ->pascal2(N, Row, Col);
    true -> io:write("done")
    end.

pascal2(N, Row, Col) ->
    if 
    Col =< Row -> calc(Row, Col);
    true -> pascal1(N, Row+1, NewCol = 0)
    end.
```

What I get from this is: `[100,111,110,101]`
What I need to get is: `1 11 121 1331`

I decided to recreate this in python in such a way that it also does not use loops. I think it is possible with recursion, but I don't think I have done it right.

```
def calc (x, y):
    if (x == 0 & (y == 0 | y == x)):
        print (1)
    else:
        print (calc(x-1, y) + calc(x-1, y-1))

def pascal(n):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    pascal1(n, row, col)

def pascal1(n, row, col):
    if row <= n:
        pascal2(n, row, col)
    else:
        print("done")

def pascal2(n, row, col):
    if col <= row:
        calc(row, col)
        pascal2(n, row, col + 1)
    else:
        pascal1(n, row + 1, col = 0)

print(pascal(3))
```

print results to `1 1 1` and a bunch of errors

Answer (score 2):

One problem here is that your functions don't return any values.  In Erlang, functions implicitly return the value of the last expression, but in Python you need to explicitly use a `return` statement.

Something like:

```py
def calc (x, y):
    if (x == 0 & (y == 0 | y == x)):
        result = 1
    else:
        result = calc(x-1, y) + calc(x-1, y-1)
    print(result)
    return result
```

And for the `pascal` function:

```py
def pascal(n):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    return pascal1(n, row, col)
```

And so on.